# socket.io Emit events firing multiple times

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've read a few questions here on SO about this subject, but I'm not sure yet how to solve it in my case. The `getMsgs` emit event is firing as many times as I've accessed the `/admin` url. I know from other questions on SO that it is because the listener is registering every time I visit the `admin` page, but I'm not sure how to refactor my code (ie where to move the `io.on(..)` and how to call it from the `router.get('/admin'..)` function.

```
router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next){
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        dal.findAllMessages(function(err, messages) {
            console.log('sent msgs');
            socket.emit('getMsgs', messages);
        });

        socket.on('newMsg', function(data){
            console.log('newMsg');
            console.log(data);
            dal.addMessage(data);
            dal.findAllMessages(function(err, messages) {
                socket.emit('getMsgs', messages);
            });
        });

        socket.on('delMsg', function(data){
            console.log('delMsg');
            console.log(data);
            dal.deleteMessage(data);
            dal.findAllMessages(function(err, messages) {
                socket.emit('getMsgs', messages);
            });
        });
    });
    res.render('admin');
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the `io.on(...)` code outside of the route.  You are re-registering a new event handler every time the `/admin` route is hit, thus you get multiple event handlers for the exact same events.

```
router.get('/admin', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('admin');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    dal.findAllMessages(function(err, messages) {
        console.log('sent msgs');
        socket.emit('getMsgs', messages);
    });

    socket.on('newMsg', function(data){
        console.log('newMsg');
        console.log(data);
        dal.addMessage(data);
        dal.findAllMessages(function(err, messages) {
            socket.emit('getMsgs', messages);
        });
    });

    socket.on('delMsg', function(data){
        console.log('delMsg');
        console.log(data);
        dal.deleteMessage(data);
        dal.findAllMessages(function(err, messages) {
            socket.emit('getMsgs', messages);
        });
    });
});
```

If you don't want the socket.io event handlers to be installed until the `/admin` route it hit, then you can keep a flag for whether they are set yet or not.

If you only want the socket.io event handlers to apply to specific admin clients, then you will need a different approach that uses some sort of authentication to decide whether a socket.io connection is allowed to connect or not.

Comment: What's an appropriate way to deal with this if you need access `req`?

Comment: @mumush - `req` only exists during a given request so it does not generically apply during socket.io events.  In other words, there is no particular http `request` object that corresponds to an incoming socket.io event.  So, your problem would have to be described in a lot more detail to understand what you're really trying to do/solve.  I'd suggest you create your own question and describe your actual situation there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `socket.removeAllListeners()`