# NodeJS/Express Room Joining when a View is accessed - Sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm creating a simple NodeJS/Express webapp that has an api and sockets. Basically, what I want to do is send data to my API from an external source, and then send this data to the socket in pageView/id. Right now it works, but it is sending data to all of the views, not the specific pageView/id.

I know I have to create Rooms and I tried doing this by having my sockets join the room when the webapp is navigated to page/id: (note I do not have logged in users)

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {

 res.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("user connected");
        //join room here 
   });

});
```

But then this creates multiple connections, every time I refresh the pageView I get a new connection + previous connections on my server side.

How can I join the room when a pageView/id is accessed? Here is my setup...

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.io = io;
  next();
});

module.exports = {app: app, server: server};
```

/bin/www

```
var app = require('../app').app;
var http = require('http');
var server = require('../app').server;
server.listen(port);
```

pageView.hbs

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('mySocket', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

pageView.js

```
router.post('/updatePage', function (req, res, next){

        //send to the view
        res.io.emit("mySocket", {
            device: device
        });
});
```

Comment: `socket.join(room)`

Comment: How? This will happen multiple times. Everytime I join the page this creates multiple connctions

Comment: and each of these connections will join a room, maybe you're confusing io and socket? http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: so it's okay that   console.log("user connected"); occurs more than once when the page is accused? The first time I access it I see "user connected" then the next time I see "user connected user connected" then the third time I see "user connected user connected user connected"

Comment: oh, no, that's not ok at all, you shouldn't see it more than once at a time? However, the connection will be reset everytime you refresh the page, so if you see "user connected" everytime, it's fine

Comment: This is basically what is happening to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697036/socket-io-emit-events-firing-multiple-times but this solution does not work for me since I have io attached to res

Comment: why would you attach it to res?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get access to the socket in my psgeView.js with my app.js and www/bin setup

Comment: ok, gotcha, gimme a minute

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand now, your mistake is to create the listeners inside your route. You need only one set of event listeners on io. So, this would work :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
     console.log("user connected");
     socket.join(room);
});

module.exports = {app: app, server: server};
```

remember that you can pass parameters on your connection, for example, you can do :

```
 var myroom = window.location.pathname.split('pageView/')[1]; //example to get room name, be creative !
    var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", { query: 'room='+myroom+' });
```

and on the server :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
         console.log("user connected");
         var room = socket.handshake.query.room; // === 'myRoom'
         socket.join(room);
         socket.emit("mySocket", {
             device: device
         });
    });
```

pageView.js

```
router.post('/updatePage', function (req, res, next){

});
```

Comment: I want the rooms to be the id's of the views for example pageView/id that id is the room name. How can I get that?? sorry I am new to this..

Comment: pass them to the query object, so your client tells the socket directly which room it needs to join. in the client you have window.location.pathname, so you have the information.

Comment: Also I don't get why we do a join in app.js and pageView.js

Comment: don't do a join in pageview

Comment: when you say "and on the server" is that also in app.js?

Comment: it can be anywhere, basically :), just don't add your socket event listeners within a route. see edits

Comment: okay, but I need to send data to the socket when my /updatePage api is hit not on connection